# How can I type the accumulator in a .reduce when returning an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm manipulating an array and reducing that to an array of objects, with strings inside. My linter is mad at the keys, saying "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'".

```
const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
acc.push({ id: `${curr}`, name: arr[curr].name});
return acc;
}, []);
```

How can I give this the proper type?

Comment: This **really** isn't a use case for `reduce`. Even for those who think `reduce` should be used outside functional programming with predefined, reusable reducers (I don't; it's just an overcomplicated loop outside that context), this is a straight-up **mapping** operation: `const newArr = arr.map(item => ({id: /*...*/, name: /*...*/}));` (I left placeholders because the code in the question doesn't seem to make much sense, you're using `curr` -- each array element -- to index into `arr`, which is odd.) Which has the added benefit that the type of the result is correctly inferred.

Comment: (If it weren't a straight-up mapping operation, a simple loop would be easier to write types for [and read, and maintain]. Again, this is assuming you're not doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions [the one above is inline].)

Comment: Thank you, I switched to mapping, which makes more sense, and didn't have to worry about the typing issue. The code I used as an example was more pseudocode to illustrate what I was attempting.